# How to chain map and filter functions in the correct order

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I really like chaining `Array.prototype.map`,  `filter` and `reduce` to define a data transformation. Unfortunately, in a recent project that involved large log files, I could no longer get away with looping through my data multiple times...

### My goal:

I want to create a function that chains `.filter` and `.map` methods by, instead of mapping over an array immediately, composing a function that loops over the data *once*. I.e.:

```
const DataTransformation = () => ({ 
    map: fn => (/* ... */), 
    filter: fn => (/* ... */), 
    run: arr => (/* ... */)
});

const someTransformation = DataTransformation()
    .map(x => x + 1)
    .filter(x => x > 3)
    .map(x => x / 2);

// returns [ 2, 2.5 ] without creating [ 2, 3, 4, 5] and [4, 5] in between
const myData = someTransformation.run([ 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

### My attempt:

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015014/mapping-an-object-to-array-of-objects-in-es6/44022167#44022167) and [this blogpost](http://raganwald.com/2017/04/30/transducers.html) I started writing a `Transduce` function.

```
const filterer = pred => reducer => (acc, x) =>
    pred(x) ? reducer(acc, x) : acc;

const mapper = map => reducer => (acc, x) =>
    reducer(acc, map(x));

const Transduce = (reducer = (acc, x) => (acc.push(x), acc)) => ({
    map: map => Transduce(mapper(map)(reducer)),
    filter: pred => Transduce(filterer(pred)(reducer)),
    run: arr => arr.reduce(reducer, [])
});
```

### The problem:

The problem with the `Transduce` snippet above, is that it runs “backwards”... The last method I chain is the first to be executed:

```
const someTransformation = Transduce()
    .map(x => x + 1)
    .filter(x => x > 3)
    .map(x => x / 2);

// Instead of [ 2, 2.5 ] this returns []
//  starts with (x / 2)       -> [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2] 
//  then filters (x < 3)      -> [] 
const myData = someTransformation.run([ 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Or, in more abstract terms:

> Go from:
>
> ```
> Transducer(concat).map(f).map(g) == (acc, x) => concat(acc, f(g(x)))
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> Transducer(concat).map(f).map(g) == (acc, x) => concat(acc, g(f(x)))
> ```
>
> Which is similar to:
>
> ```
> mapper(f) (mapper(g) (concat))
> ```

I think I understand *why* it happens, but I can't figure out how to fix it without changing the “interface” of my function.

### The question:

How can I make my `Transduce` method chain `filter` and `map` operations in the correct order?

---

#### Notes:

- I'm only just learning about the naming of some of the things I'm trying to do. Please let me know if I've incorrectly used the `Transduce` term or if there are better ways to describe the problem.
- I'm aware I can do the same using a nested `for` loop:

```js
const push = (acc, x) => (acc.push(x), acc);
const ActionChain = (actions = []) => {
  const run = arr =>
    arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
      for (let i = 0, action; i < actions.length; i += 1) {
        action = actions[i];

        if (action.type === "FILTER") {
          if (action.fn(x)) {
            continue;
          }

          return acc;
        } else if (action.type === "MAP") {
          x = action.fn(x);
        }
      }

      acc.push(x);
      return acc;
    }, []);

  const addAction = type => fn => 
    ActionChain(push(actions, { type, fn }));

  return {
    map: addAction("MAP"),
    filter: addAction("FILTER"),
    run
  };
};

// Compare to regular chain to check if 
// there's a performance gain
// Admittedly, in this example, it's quite small...
const naiveApproach = {
  run: arr =>
    arr
      .map(x => x + 3)
      .filter(x => x % 3 === 0)
      .map(x => x / 3)
      .filter(x => x < 40)
};

const actionChain = ActionChain()
  .map(x => x + 3)
  .filter(x => x % 3 === 0)
  .map(x => x / 3)
  .filter(x => x < 40)


const testData = Array.from(Array(100000), (x, i) => i);

console.time("naive");
const result1 = naiveApproach.run(testData);
console.timeEnd("naive");

console.time("chain");
const result2 = actionChain.run(testData);
console.timeEnd("chain");
console.log("equal:", JSON.stringify(result1) === JSON.stringify(result2));
```

- Here's my attempt in a stack snippet:

```js
const filterer = pred => reducer => (acc, x) =>
  pred(x) ? reducer(acc, x) : acc;

const mapper = map => reducer => (acc, x) => reducer(acc, map(x));

const Transduce = (reducer = (acc, x) => (acc.push(x), acc)) => ({
  map: map => Transduce(mapper(map)(reducer)),
  filter: pred => Transduce(filterer(pred)(reducer)),
  run: arr => arr.reduce(reducer, [])
});

const sameDataTransformation = Transduce()
  .map(x => x + 5)
  .filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
  .map(x => x / 2)
  .filter(x => x < 4);
  
// It's backwards:
// [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
// [-0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5]
// [0]
// [5]
console.log(sameDataTransformation.run([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: map: map => Transduce(mapper(map)(reducer)), means: return a function that maps first, then does the original reducing.

Comment: Transducer build a stack. Try `run: arr => arr.reduceRight(reducer, [])`

Comment: @ftor I wanted to make the `reducer` in `run` be a composition of all `map` and `filter` methods previously passed. I think the problem is not the order of which I reduce my `arr` with data, but the way I'm failing to correctly return a new `reducer` method. E.g.: `mapper(f) (mapper(g) (concat));` returns a reducer similar to `(acc, x) => concat(acc, g(f(x)))`, whereas my `Transduce(concat).map(f).map(g)` returns  `(acc, x) => concat(acc, f(g(x)))`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**before we know better**

> I really like chaining ...

I see that, and I'll appease you, but you'll come to understand that forcing your program through a chaining API is unnatural, and more trouble than it's worth in most cases.

> ```
> const Transduce = (reducer = (acc, x) => (acc.push(x), acc)) => ({
>   map: map => Transduce(mapper(map)(reducer)),
>   filter: pred => Transduce(filterer(pred)(reducer)),
>   run: arr => arr.reduce(reducer, [])
> });
> ```
>
> I think I understand why it happens, but I can't figure out how to fix it without changing the “interface” of my function.

The problem is indeed with your `Transduce` constructor. Your `map` and `filter` methods are stacking `map` and `pred` on the outside of the transducer chain, instead of nesting them inside.

Below, I've implemented your `Transduce` API that evaluates the maps and filters in correct order. I've also added a `log` method so that we can see how `Transduce` is behaving

```js
const Transduce = (f = k => k) => ({
  map: g =>
    Transduce(k =>
      f ((acc, x) => k(acc, g(x)))),
  filter: g =>
    Transduce(k =>
      f ((acc, x) => g(x) ? k(acc, x) : acc)),
  log: s =>
    Transduce(k =>
      f ((acc, x) => (console.log(s, x), k(acc, x)))),
  run: xs =>
    xs.reduce(f((acc, x) => acc.concat(x)), [])
})

const foo = nums => {
  return Transduce()
    .log('greater than 2?')
    .filter(x => x > 2)
    .log('\tsquare:')
    .map(x => x * x)
    .log('\t\tless than 30?')
    .filter(x => x < 30)
    .log('\t\t\tpass')
    .run(nums)
}

// keep square(n), forall n of nums
//   where n > 2
//   where square(n) < 30
console.log(foo([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
// => [ 9, 16, 25 ]
```

---

**untapped potential**

> Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015014/mapping-an-object-to-array-of-objects-in-es6/44022167#44022167) ...

In reading that answer I wrote, you overlook the generic quality of `Trans` as it was written there. Here, our `Transduce` only attempts to work with Arrays, but really it can work with any type that has an empty value (`[]`) and a `concat` method. These two properties make up a category called [Monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) and we'd be doing ourselves a disservice if we didn't take advantage of transducer's ability to work with any type in this category.

Above, we hard-coded the initial accumulator `[]` in the `run` method, but this should probably be supplied as an argument – much like we do with `iterable.reduce(reducer, initialAcc)`

Aside from that, both implementations are essentially equivalent. The biggest difference is that the `Trans` implementation provided in the linked answer is `Trans` itself is a monoid, but `Transduce` here is not. `Trans` neatly implements composition of transducers in the `concat` method whereas `Transduce` (above) has composition mixed within each method. Making it a monoid allows us to rationalize `Trans` the same way do all other monoids, instead of having to understand it as some specialized chaining interface with unique `map`, `filter`, and `run` methods.

I would advise building from `Trans` instead of making your own custom API

---

**have your cake and eat it too**

So we learned the valuable lesson of uniform interfaces and we understand that `Trans` is inherently simple. But, you still want that sweet chaining API. OK, ok...

We're going to implement `Transduce` one more time, but this time we'll do so using the `Trans` monoid. Here, `Transduce` holds a `Trans` value instead of a continuation (`Function`).

Everything else stays the same – `foo` takes 1 *tiny* change and produces an identical output.

```
// generic transducers
const mapper = f =>
  Trans(k => (acc, x) => k(acc, f(x)))

const filterer = f =>
  Trans(k => (acc, x) => f(x) ? k(acc, x) : acc)

const logger = label =>
  Trans(k => (acc, x) => (console.log(label, x), k(acc, x)))

// magic chaining api made with Trans monoid
const Transduce = (t = Trans.empty()) => ({
  map: f =>
    Transduce(t.concat(mapper(f))),
  filter: f =>
    Transduce(t.concat(filterer(f))),
  log: s =>
    Transduce(t.concat(logger(s))),
  run: (m, xs) =>
    transduce(t, m, xs)
})

// when we run, we must specify the type to transduce
//   .run(Array, nums)
// instead of
//   .run(nums)
```

Expand this code snippet to see the final implementation – of course you could skip defining a separate `mapper`, `filterer`, and `logger`, and instead define those directly on `Transduce`. I think this reads nicer tho.

```js
// Trans monoid
const Trans = f => ({
  runTrans: f,
  concat: ({runTrans: g}) =>
    Trans(k => f(g(k)))
})

Trans.empty = () =>
  Trans(k => k)

const transduce = (t, m, xs) =>
  xs.reduce(t.runTrans((acc, x) => acc.concat(x)), m.empty())

// complete Array monoid implementation
Array.empty = () => []

// generic transducers
const mapper = f =>
  Trans(k => (acc, x) => k(acc, f(x)))
  
const filterer = f =>
  Trans(k => (acc, x) => f(x) ? k(acc, x) : acc)
  
const logger = label =>
  Trans(k => (acc, x) => (console.log(label, x), k(acc, x)))

// now implemented with Trans monoid
const Transduce = (t = Trans.empty()) => ({
  map: f =>
    Transduce(t.concat(mapper(f))),
  filter: f =>
    Transduce(t.concat(filterer(f))),
  log: s =>
    Transduce(t.concat(logger(s))),
  run: (m, xs) =>
    transduce(t, m, xs)
})

// this stays exactly the same
const foo = nums => {
  return Transduce()
    .log('greater than 2?')
    .filter(x => x > 2)
    .log('\tsquare:')
    .map(x => x * x)
    .log('\t\tless than 30?')
    .filter(x => x < 30)
    .log('\t\t\tpass')
    .run(Array, nums)
}

// output is exactly the same
console.log(foo([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
// => [ 9, 16, 25 ]
```

---

**wrap up**

So we started with a mess of lambdas and then made things simpler using a monoid. The `Trans` monoid provides distinct advantages in that the monoid interface is known and the generic implementation is *extremely* simple. But we're stubborn or maybe we have goals to fulfill that are not set by us – we decide to build the magic `Transduce` chaining API, but we do so using our rock-solid `Trans` monoid which gives us all the power of `Trans` but also keeps complexity nicely compartmentalised.

---

**dot chaining fetishists anonymous**

Here's a couple other recent answers I wrote about method chaining

- [Is there any way to make a functions return accessible via a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105026/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-functions-return-accessible-via-a-property/44109078#44109078)
- [Chaining functions and using an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332929/javascript-functional-programming-chaining-functions-and-using-an-anonymous-fu/43333735#43333735)
- [Pass result of functional chain to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129434/pass-result-of-functional-chain-to-function/44129633#44129633)

Comment: What a great answer! I had hoped to make things easier for myself by skipping some of the "abstract" stuff and making the code less general (i.e. only apply to arrays), but I see now that it doesn't always work that way... I'll have to admit that some of the concepts you're referring to (like η-conversion and Monoids) are still hard for me to grasp. But I really appreciate that you didn't just leave it at the quick fix ("but that's UGLY" – haha!) and took the time to explain, step-by-step, the concepts that help you solve such problems in a structured way.

Comment: Nice! Notice that the eta conversion works on the tupled function as well, no need to curry it

Comment: @Bergi, I thought there was something off with that. My intuition said it should've been possible, but when I tried it earlier, I must've made a mistake or something. Thanks for catching that, it cleaned up the answer significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the order of your implementations:

```
const filterer = pred => reducer => (x) =>pred((a=reducer(x) )?x: undefined;

const mapper = map => reducer => (x) => map(reducer(x));
```

Then you need to change the run command to:

```
run: arr => arr.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat([reducer(b)]), []);
```

And the default reducer must be

```
x=>x
```

However, this way the filter wont work. You may throw undefined in the filter function and catch in the run function:

```
run: arr => arr.reduce((a,b)=>{
try{
 a.push(reducer(b));
}catch(e){}
return a;
}, []);

const filterer = pred => reducer => (x) =>{
 if(!pred((a=reducer(x))){
   throw undefined;
 }
 return x;
};
```

However, all in all i think the for loop is much more elegant in this case...

Comment: I don't think this works since my `pred` is a function of `x -> bool` and `map` is `x -> y`. This makes the reducer run first, returning an array (at least in my current example). Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @user3297291 you were right. You also needed to change run and the default reducer http://jsbin.com/laqezabihe/edit?console

Comment: The crux of the problem is really in supporting `filter` it seems. I agree that the `for` loop option beats having to resort to a `try {} catch () {}`...