# Array .filter and .map OR .map with a if condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Recently I was doing some sort of filter to an array and I came up with two cases and I don't know which one to use.

In terms of **performance**, which is better to use.

```
arr.filter(someCondition).map(x => x.something)
```

Or

```
arr.map(x => {
    if(someCondition) {
        return x.something
    }
})
```

**One thing to notice is that I'm using react, so have `undefined` values in the returning array (don't return any thing inside `.map`), it's totally acceptable.**

This involves a lot of questions like, how many elements you have in the array and how many you of then will pass the condition and that is what make be wonder which one is better.

So, considering n elements and cases where all elements pass the condition and also that no elements pass the condition, which one have better performance?

`.filter().map()` OR  `.map` with `if` inside?

Comment: For performance? Usually the `map` with `if` should be faster, since you only iterate over the data once. However, in many cases it probably doesn't matter. Have you timed it?

Comment: `map` can't filter items, they (map and filter) are **not** the same. If you want to do that in a single loop that needs to filter and actually transform value, just do a function or an external method if you care that much about performances, use a function generator with a callback or, probably more suitable for your use case `.reduce`, which allows to filter and map in a single shot.

Comment: Please notice that is ok to return `undefined`. I know the result is different, but for my case, in react, it's going to be the same

Comment: @Vencovsky I know it's ok, I'm just wondering whether using `.reduce` would be a solution, since it will actually iterate the array once and allow to both filter and map at the same time.

Comment: @briosheje how would that be?

Comment: @VLAZ how would I time it if there is cases where all elements can pass the condition but also none can pass the condition ?

Comment: I would recommend you to focus on readability, try to make your code *expressive*, rather than on focusing on "performance". I quote "performance" because the benefits would be most likely negligible. If I were reviewing your code, and I see using `map` with an `if` condition, not returning anything for the false case, would have certainly made me think and see what is happening... Remember, you spend most of the time *reading* code.

Comment: @Vencovsky `arr.reduce((acc, next) => { return (someCondition && acc.push(next.something)), acc }, []);` or something like that (that's the shortest I came up with, you should make it more readable though). Basically, if `someCondition` is truthy, it will push `x.something` to the accumulator (a brand new empty array). In that scenario, `arr` is iterated once only and will come up with a new array holding all the "mapped" values filtered by your condition. Not sure whether it is less performant than map, but it shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: @Vencovsky all can pass but also none can pass? I can only assume that you meant that as two different occasions, as it makes no sense to happen *at the same time*. At any rate - if *none* pass the condition, then you'd end up with `n` operations - you'd go over the array once. With `filter`, you'd have an empty array and running `.map` will be a no-op. That's the same complexity as `map/if`. But if *all* pass, then you'd end up with `2n` operations - `n` for `filter` and another `n` for `map`. `map/if` still runs only `n` times. You still need to time it to see which works better, if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: It's really unlikely to matter.

But: **Only** because it's okay in your case to have `undefined` in the result array, the second one will be faster.

Let's compare:

The first way, `filter` has to make a pass through the entire array, creating a new array with the accepted entries, then `map` has to make a pass through the new array and make a new array of the `something` properties.

The second way, `map` makes one pass through the array, creating a new array with the `something` properties (or `undefined` for the ones that would have been filtered out).

Of course, this assumes you aren't just offloading the burden elsewhere (e.g., if React has to do something to ignore those `undefined`s).

But again: It's unlikely to matter.

I would probably use a third option: Build the result array yourself:

```
const result = [];
for (const x of arr) {
    if(someCondition) {
        result[result.length] = x.something;
    }
}
```

That still makes just one pass, but doesn't produce an array with `undefined` in it. (You can also shoehorn that into a `reduce`, but it doesn't buy you anything but complexity.)

*(Don't worry about `for-of` requiring an iterator. It gets [optimized away](https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1157287966458486784) in "hot" code.)*

Comment: Wouldn't using reduce benefit on react's performances? I know react already handles undefined values, but a smaller array should benefit rather than a dirty one generated through a mapping that returns (maybe) several undefined values, no?

Comment: You say `It's really unlikely to matter` because even with huge sets you won't be able to see the difference between both?

Comment: @briosheje - As I said, I'd produce an array that doesn't have those, with a single pass, without using `reduce` as there's no reason to. :-)

Comment: @Vencovsky - Right, in most cases whatever you're doing with the result is what takes the time. Of course, every once in a while, it *does* matter. Just not often. :-)

Comment: @Vencovsky Not on "javascript"'s side, I mean, you still will need to iterate the entire array in any case, the only benefit I can foresee is that react would handle a smaller array if you produce that with other prototypes (so, neither map, nor filter).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So you would do that with a regular for? any reason for not using `reduce`? Just wondering... I wouldn't use reduce either, I would use a function generator for that, just wondering how you would do that without reduce :)

Comment: @briosheje basically you'd do something very similar to [this](https://jsbin.com/carudahaba/edit?js,console). Although, if you want something more reusable and more FP, you can employ [a transducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198833/how-to-chain-map-and-filter-functions-in-the-correct-order/44211131#44211131) which serves to take a bunch of callbacks intended for `.filter` and `.map` and do a single pass through the array while evaluating and acting on them all.

Comment: @briosheje - I don't use `reduce` when the value being passed around never changes. It wouldn't change in this case (it's always a reference to the same array). Increasingly, [like Brian Terlson](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544), I'm tending not to use `reduce` virtually at all. So yes, I'd use a `for` loop, or `forEach` as above, or a `for-of` loop (I didn't use `for-of` above to avoid the iterator overhead), etc.

Comment: @vlaz I would've done reduce in this way, I was just wondering whether other cleverer approaches existed. Again, I personally would've handled that differently, just wondering why no one other than me apparently thought about reduce in the first place, which is weird to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, so you would handle that with a for loop, that's what I was wondering :P.

Comment: @briosheje - Or `forEach` or `for-of`, yeah. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm still astonished about that `reduce` hostility, though. I've been using that for ages when I needed to perform a whole lot of things on arrays.. Even in C# (using .Aggregate). Just wondering why Brian is rejecting it, lol.

Comment: @briosheje do check out the transducers link. It actually happens to be one of my favourite posts in SO, since it's pretty informative. Also, this would be your cleverer use of `reduce` - it shines if you have to do a lot of operations on an array.

Comment: @VLAZ yep I'm looking at it, thanks. I usually use reduce when I need to do multiple operations on element (when input elements of A are entirely different of expected output elements both in length and format) or use reduce to perform sums and stuff like that on arrays. Other than that, I usually abuse function generators, not sure whether it's a good thing, but I like their flexibility, not sure whether they're also that performant, but hey, on small datasets (as you already mentioned) the performance is negligible.

Answer (score 4):

You could use reduce function instead of map and filter and it wouldn't return you undefined like when you use map and if.

```
arr.reduce((acc, x) => (someCondition ? [...acc, x.something] : acc), [])
```

or

```
arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  if (someCondition) {
    acc.push(x.something);
    return acc;
  } else return acc;
}, []);
```

As @briosheje said smaller array would be a plus. As it reduces number of rerendering in your React app where you use this array and it is unnecessary to pass undefined. Reduce function would be much more efficient, I would say.

If you are wondering why I have written 1st one using spread operator and 2nd one without it is because the execution time taken for 1st one is more compared to 2nd one. And that is due to spread operator as it is cloning 'acc'. So if you want lesser execution time go for 2nd one or else if you want lesser LOC go for 1st one