# Why does compose apply left to right with transducers?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, transducer

Example code:

```
// Compose functionality
const compose = (...fns) => {
  return args => {
    return fns.reduceRight((arg, fn) => fn(arg), args);
  }
};

// List of transformation and predicate functions
const add1 = x => x + 1;
const isGreaterThanThree = x => x > 3;
const times2 = x => x * 2;

// Concat and Sum reducers (or the thing that I want to build). 
/*
  In this case, I'm using concatReducer, but I can easily substitute concatReducer with
  sumReducer and change the initial value of the reduce method to zero.
*/
const concatReducer = (acc, el) => acc.concat(el);
const sumReducer = (acc, el) => acc += el;

// Transformation reducer (not sure the appropriate terminology)
const mapReducer = transform => {
  return reducer => {
    return (acc, el) => {
      return reducer(acc, transform(el));
    }
  }
};

// Predicate reducer (again, not sure the appropriate terminology here)
const filterReducer = predicate => {
  return reducer => {
    return (acc, el) => {
      return predicate(el) ? reducer(acc, el) : acc;
    }
  }
}

[1, 2, 3] 
  .reduce(
    compose(
      mapReducer(times2),
      filterReducer(isGreaterThanThree),
      mapReducer(add1),
    )(concatReducer),
    []
  );
```

I expect the value to be [ 8 ] instead of [ 5, 7 ].

Compose is a right-associative (reduceRight), but in this case, it is behaving as left-associative.

I thought to myself that maybe my compose function implementation was wrong.
As a result, I pulled in [ramda.js](/questions/tagged/ramda.js) and used R.compose, but I got the same result.

**Am I doing something wrong? Or is this one of those scenarios that compose is left-associative when dealing with transducers?**

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198833/how-to-chain-map-and-filter-functions-in-the-correct-order) once and got [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44211131/3297291). Maybe it helps 

Answer (score 2):

Quotes and some of the examples are taken from https://github.com/cognitect-labs/transducers-js.

### What is a transducer?

> Transducers are simply a function of one arity. The only argument is another transducer transformer (labeled xf in the code base).

> Since transducers are simply functions of one argument they can be composed easily via function composition to create transformer pipelines. Note that transducers return transformers when invoked.

Example: (adapted)

```js
var mapper = function(f) {
  return function(xf) {    // <- This is a transducer, it takes a transformer xf
    return Mapper(f, xf);  // <- and it returns another transformer xf'
  };
};
```

*Note: we'll cover `Mapper` later.*

Let's rewrite with some arrow functions:

```js
var mapper = f => xf => Mapper(f, xf);
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                This is a transducer
```

In the snippet above it should be clearer that a transducer is indeed a function that takes a transformer and returns another transformer. These two compositions are equal:

```js
compose(mapper(double), mapper(inc))

compose(xf => Mapper(double, xf), xf => Mapper(inc, xf))
```

**Fun fact**

The function composition now waits for the initial transformer which is commonly referred to as the "step" transformer (or "step" function) which is responsible for accumulating the transformation into a container.

A typical container would be either an array, a string or an object. Such "step" transformer would either:

- push to an array *(we'll refer to such transformer as `Push` in the rest of this answer)*
- or append to a string
- or set a property on a object

But we don't need to know the details of such transformer. However we do need to understand what transformers are.

### What is a transformer?

> Transformers are objects. They must implement 3 methods, `@@transducer/init`, `@@transducer/result` and `@@transducer/step`. If a transformer is intended to be composed with other transformers they should either close over the next transformer or store it in a field.

Example: (adapted)

```js
var Mapper = function(f, xf) {
  return { // <-- This is a transformer
    "@@transducer/init": function() { 
      return xf["@@transducer/init"](); 
    },
    "@@transducer/result": function(result) { 
      return xf["@@transducer/result"](result); 
    },
    "@@transducer/step": function(result, input) {
      return xf["@@transducer/step"](result, f(input));
      //                                     ^^^^^^^^
      //                                     e.g. inc(41)
    }
  };
};
```

In order to understand why transducers reverse the order of the composition, we need to take a closer look at the `@@transducer/step` method:

```js
"@@transducer/step": function(result, input) {
  return xf["@@transducer/step"](result, f(input));
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^
//       called last                     called first!
```

*Note: `result` is the container into which we will accumulate the transformations.*

When you do:

```js
compose(mapper(double), mapper(inc))(Push())
```

You end up with a final transformer that looks like this:

```js
const xfinal = Mapper(double, Mapper(inc, push));
```

Usually your library will do this for you but for educational purpose we will call the the `@@transducer/step` method on that final transformer and decompose the functions calls:

```js
xfinal['@@transducer/step']([], 20)
```

Is similar to:

```
Mapper(double, Mapper(inc, push))([], 20)
       ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       f       xf

Mapper(inc, push)([], double(20))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
xf     ^^^  ^^^^
       f'   xf'

push([], inc(double(20)))
^^^^     ^^^ ^^^^^^
xf'      f'  f
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         HERE!
```

Even though we did `compose(mapper(double), mapper(inc))` we can see that the `double` function got applied *before* `inc` did. This isn't a bug in the `compose` function, it is simply how transformers are supposed to work when composed together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I need to read this multiple times in order to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Because you apply the composed transducers (`f,g,h`) to a reducer (`r`),  the leftmost (`f`) becomes topmost, first to act on the eventual arguments `(acc, el)` to the augmented reducer `f( g(h(r)) )`:<sup>(*)</sup>

```
compose(f,g,h)(r)(acc, el) =~= f( g( h( r)) )(acc, el)
                                  <--------
                               --...........->
```

Indeed the rightmost, `h`, is applied to the argument `r` *first*; but that `r` is also a function; the whole composed thing is a function; and the composed function has `f` as its first component, so it is *`f`* that gets to work on the *next* arguments `(acc, el)` *first*, using the result of the inner composition `g( h( r))` according to the definition of `f`.

What we have here, is

```
       r        //  reducer
    h           // transducer
    h( r )      //  reducer
  g             // transducer
  g(h( r ))     //  reducer
f               // transducer
f(g(h( r )))    //  reducer
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> So you have defined your functions so that

```
mapReducer(foo)(reducer)(acc, el) 
  =~= reducer(acc, foo(el));

filterReducer(predicate)(reducer)(acc, el)
  =~= predicate(el) ? reducer(acc, el) : acc;

concatReducer(acc, el)
  =~= acc.concat(el);
```

and, most importantly,

```
compose(f,g,h,...,p,q)(r)
    =~= [f,g,h,...,p,q].reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), r);
    =~= f(g(h(...(p(q( r ))...)))
```

So then

```
[1, 2, 3] 
  .reduce(
    compose(
      f,               // f = mapReducer(times2),
      g,               // g = filterReducer(isGreaterThanThree),
      h                // h = mapReducer(add1),
      )(r),            // r = concatReducer
    []
  )
  =~= [1, 2, 3] .reduce( f(g(h(r))), [])     // rc = f(g(h(r)))
  =~= rc( rc( rc( [], 1),  2),  3)
  =~= rc( rc( f(g(h(r)))( [], 1),  2),  3)
  =~= rc( rc( mapReducer(times2)(g(h(r)))( [], 1 ),  2),  3)

           // mapReducer(foo   )(reducer)(acc, el)
           //                =~= reducer( acc, foo(el))

  =~= rc( rc( g(h(r))([], times2( 1)),  2),  3)
  =~= rc( rc( filterReducer(isGreaterThanThree)(h(r))([] , times2( 1)),  
            2), 
        3)

           // filterReducer(pred           )(reducer)(acc, el)
           //                =~= pred(el) ?  reducer( acc, el) : acc

  =~= rc( rc( isGreaterThanThree( twice1) ? h(r)(  [], twice1) : [],  
            2),          /* where twice1 = times2(1) 
                                  h = mapReducer( add1) */
        3)
  =~= rc( rc( isGreaterThanThree( twice1) ? r([], add1(twice1)) : [],  
            2),          /* where twice1 = times2(1) 
                                  r = concatReducer  */
        3)
  =~= rc( rc( isGreaterThanThree( twice1) ? [].concat(add1(twice1)) : [],  
            2),          /* where twice1 = times2(1) */
        3)
  =~= ...
```

and we can see that `mapReducer(times2)` gets to work on the list's elements *first*, before the filtering by `isGreaterThanThree` and then the mapping of `add1`.

In processing the `[1,2,3]`, first the mapping of `times2` is done (implicitly *as-if* making it `[2,4,6]`), then the filtering (which would leave just  `[4,6]`), and then the mapping of `add1`, for the final result of `[5,7]` indeed.

There's no creating the interim structure though. Instead one composite reducer is built, and used by one `reduce`, advancing along the input one step at a time.

Thus transducers are a *fusion / deforestation* technique. Intuitively, nested folds should fuse, eliminating the need for the interim structure creation by an inner fold only so it can be consumed by the wrapping fold; following the transducer discipline lets us achieve just that.

---

So then, `mapReducer` and `filterReducer` are badly named. They are actually `mappingTransducer_Maker` (or just `mapping`) and `filteringTransducer_Maker` (or just `filtering`), where

- `mapping(foo)` is a *mapping* transducer that applies `foo` to the input's element `elt`, resulting in `foo(elt)`, and
- `filtering(pred)` is a *filtering* transducer that filters out the input's element `el` according to the predicate call `pred(el)`, or keeps it in.

Or rather, a transducer augments its argument `reducer` so that when the combined, augmented reducer is finally called with the accumulator and the current element, it manipulates the element and the accumulator in a prescribed way before passing the results to the base `reducer`:

```
mapping(foo)( filtering(pred)(reducer) )( acc, elt)
----------------------------------------(         )
 =~=
filtering(pred)(reducer)( acc, foo(elt) )
 =~=
pred( foo(elt) ) ? reducer( acc, foo(elt) ) : acc
```

So, `mapping(foo)` and `filtering(pred)` are composed right-to-left with respect to their argument, `reducer`; but then the composed reducer starts working from the top, tracing the transducers' effects left-to-right -- first doing the mapping, and doing the filtering after that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Correct if I'm wrong, but in my case, the composition for concatReducer still goes from right to left applying first mapReducer(times2), filterReducer(isGreaterThanThree), and then mapReducer(add1), which returns a wrapper function that accepts an argument (x). However, when x is passed into the wrapper function, x actually goes into mapReducer(times2) first and then the other functions. Is this correct?

Comment: @FNMT8L9IN82 the mapReducer and filterReducer are actually transducers, not reducers. you compose the transducers, and the composed transducer is applied to concatReducer, resulting in an augmented reducer, which gets to work on the actual elements and the accumulator versions (as it is changed with progression along the input). `[1, 2, 3] .reduce( f(g(h(r))), []) = [2,3].reduce( f(g(h(r))), f(g(h(r)))( [], 1) )` according to the definiition of `reduce`. the reducers accept pairs, `(accum, elemt)`. so `x` in my `compose` is a pair `(accum, elemt)`. it's symbolic.

Comment: don't hesitate to ask more, if needed. :)