# Map and filter in one method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

The following code processes a list of file paths and should return only the file names (without extension) of XML files. Currently I got to this:

```js
const filteredFiles = files
  .map(f => f.match(/.*\/(.*)\.xml/)) // map to regex match with capture
  .filter(v => v)                     // non-matches returned null and will be filtered out here
  .map(m => m[1])                     // map out the regex capture
```

I find this code quite cumbersome. Is there no way to combine the matching and filtering in a more "efficient" way? And by "efficient" I mean code-readable-efficient and not time-efficient as the input array holds 100 values at most but most of the time between 10 and 20.

Comment: Using foreach and pushing altered elements to filteredFiles in foreach might be what you want. I think it is more code-readable-efficient.

Comment: If are looking in this way to optimize your code or it should iterate only once. so you can use `.reduce`  example `files.reduce((r, f) => { const value = f.match(/.*\/(.*)\.xml/); if (value?.[1]) { return [...r, value[1]]} return r;},[])`

Comment: This could be of interest: [How to chain map and filter functions in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44198833)

Answer (score 2):

*Map and filter*, otherwise known as [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const rx = /\/(.*)\.xml$/;

const filteredFiles = files.reduce((arr, f) => {
  const match = f.match(rx);
  return match ? [...arr, match[1]] : arr;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve your need of mapping and filtering out the non matching values in one shot... but it makes one step easier by using the optional chaining operator `?.`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

I also slightly changed the regex to allow the filename with no path specifed.

```js
const files = [
  './path/to/filename_01.xml',
  'non_matching_value',
  './path/to/filename_02.xml',
  './path/to/filename_03.xml',
  './path/to/filename_04.xml',
  'filename_05.xml',
];

//Approach using filter over map to ignore non matching array items
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const filteredFiles = files
  .map(filename => filename.match(/^(.*\/)?(.*)\.xml/)?.[2])
  .filter(filename => filename);
  
console.log(filteredFiles);

//Approach using flatMap as suggested by another user answering the same question
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const filteredFiles2 = files.flatMap((f)=>{
  //here you are forced to put the match result in a dedicated variable..
  const match = f.match(/^(.*\/)?(.*)\.xml/);
  //because you need to use it both on the condition and the positive outcome
  return ( match ) ? [match[2]] : [];
});

console.log(filteredFiles2);

//Approach using flatMap as suggested by another user answering the same question
//AND using the null coealeshing operator to return empty array in case of non matching string
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const filteredFiles3 = files.flatMap(f => f.match(/^(.*\/)?(.*)\.xml/)?.[2] ?? []);

console.log(filteredFiles3);
```

Comment: Didn't think of optional chaining. Could be great in combination with `.flatMap(… ?? [])` (suggested by @mousetail) so I can drop the `.filter()` but don't know about code readability.

Comment: well it would be hard to fit `.?` in that exact scenario because the alternative option to returning a filled array it's an empty array. But to collapse the whole if statement a ternary operator would be suitable in that case: `return (match) ? [match[1]] : [];`

Comment: `?.` would return `undefined` if n/a so I guess you could use the default operator here `.flatMap(f => f.match(/^(.*\/)?(.*)\.xml/)?.[2] ?? [])`?

Comment: yes you did it right.. I also updated my question showing all those 3 different approaches

Answer (score 2):

As I added in comment, you could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of array to achieve this in single iteration

**Example**

```js
const regex = /\/(.*)\.xml$/;

const filteredFiles = files.reduce((r, f) => {
  const value = f.match(regex);
  if (value?.[1]) {
    return [...r, value[1]];//If matches found then return previous result + new value 
  }
  return r; // If not matches found then return previous result 
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (ab)use [flat map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const filteredFiles = files.flatMap((f)=>{
  let match = f.match('...');
  if (match) {
      return [match[1]]
  } else {
      return []
  }
})
```

Not sure if it's actually better than the original though.

Comment: what if `match[1]` is `undefined` ?

Comment: @NarendraJadhav `match` will be `null` if the regex doesn't match.

Comment: Great idea. I could combine it with the optional chaining (suggested by @diego-de-vita). Still struggling on the code readability though.